# How to get HWND and click for Menu/SubMenu/SubMenuItem?

Tags: winapi, user-interface

I'm working on an App and it has SubMenu/One more child SubMenu like Edit --> Insert --> Date and few other option. I want to click(sendmessage) to Date menuitem. is there any PinvokeMethod to get handle for multilevel menu Items?

Answer (score 3):

To simulate the click of a menu you do not send any message to the menu itself, you just send the same message that the menu does when clicked. That is, send `WM_COMMAND` to the owner window of the menu, with old good `SendMessage`.

When choosing an option from a menu, the parameters are:

- `wParam`: the identifier (16 lower bits) of the command to be sent.
- `lParam`: `0`.

If you don't know the value of the identifier, you can use a monitor program such as `Spy++` (included with most VS versions) to list the messages sent/received by your program.

Comment: Here is my task..  Edit (Menu) - Insert (Submenu) - Date (Another inside menu)..   IntPtr tedMenu = InvokeMethods.GetMenu(tNoteHandle);
            IntPtr tedSubMenu = InvokeMethods.GetSubMenu(tedMenu,1);          
            uint menuItemId = InvokeMethods.GetMenuItemID(tedSubMenu,6);            
            InvokeMethods.PostMessage(tNoteHandle, (uint)0x0111, (IntPtr)menuItemId, IntPtr.Zero);  How to click Date mentuItem on child submenu?